# How to download table created in supabase

Tags: nosql, supabase, supabase-database

I've created a table in supabase and filled it up with some data, Is there any way to download this table without interacting with supabase client?

I want to save this as CSV file for future use but there's no apparent feature to extract the entire table from supabase.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [SQL Editor](https://app.supabase.com/project/_/sql) and run the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name`;
```

Then, you can click on results -> Download CSV:
[image]

Comment: does not work properly if too many rows

Answer (score 2):

Mansueli is right! I would like to add that if you get the error that your table does not exist, run the following:

```
SELECT * FROM public."table_name";
```